# OxyPlot draws circle incorrectly (with gap)

Tags: c#, math, oxyplot

I typed this:

```
myModel.Series.Add(new FunctionSeries((x) => Math.Sqrt(16 - Math.Pow(x, 2)), -4, 4, 0.1, "x^2 + y^2 = 16") { Color = OxyColors.Red });
myModel.Series.Add(new FunctionSeries((x) => - Math.Sqrt(16 - Math.Pow(x, 2)), -4, 4, 0.1) { Color = OxyColors.Red });
```

And OxyPlot drew it:

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because

```
Math.Sqrt(16 - Math.Pow(x, 2))
```

returns `NaN` for `x = 4` because `16 - Math.Pow(x, 2)` is calculated by double precision. This means the result equals not exactly 0 (`-3,5527136788005E-14` in this case). A negative square root like `Math.Sqrt(-3,5527136788005E-14)` is undefined like described at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sqrt(v=vs.110).aspx).

You could fix it by prohibiting negative numbers. Just take the maximum of your calculation and 0 like

```
Math.Sqrt(Math.Max(16 - Math.Pow(x, 2), 0))
```

Comment: Thats not correct @dlatikay ... if x is 0 the result would be valid. x = 4 would be invalid.

Comment: aaaargh embarrassed twice on the same post today :-) of course, thanks. anyway +1 for including a possible solution in the answer instead of just spotting the mistake.

Comment: Hmm, i don't know why Math.Sqrt doesn't accept expression with 4 but accepts expression with -4, but solution with `double.Epsilon` works.

Comment: the reasoning is that 16-4² = 16-16 = 0 and sqrt(0) gives NaN. I could not see that from the MSDN article that @fruchtzwerg linked, because it says that the sqrt of 0 is 0 and my pocket calculator thinks so too. I suspect a different reason for this problem. When we look at the source code of OxyPlot where it computes its graphs, we find that they have added [some kind of epsilon to their loop](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/fe84b034c1105fd0cd679d8cedd88d9c20fde417/Source/OxyPlot/Series/FunctionSeries.cs#L38), and the argument gets actually negative due to that.

Comment: Thanks for this response @dlatikay - you are totally correct. My explanation was a little bit misleading. I don't see any kind of epsilon in the code of OxyPlot but I've updated my answer to explain the behaviour correctly. Thanks!

Comment: they're not looping to x2 (4.0) but to x2 + (dx * 0.5) which is 4.05 and drives the argument as low as -0.4025. anyway, the intricacies of the double data type explain the original problem, so perfect answer now.

Comment: They are looping to  `x <= x1 + (dx * 0.5)` which means `x1` is included and  `x1 + dx` not. In theory it's exactly the same as `x < x1 + dx`but because of double precision errors they are choosing the first way. This means `4` and `-4` is incuded. Check http://rextester.com/CCBP62962